# Python crashes during category transformation

Tags: python, pandas, categories

I have a dataframe with around 200,000 observations and several variables. I want to run a regression and use one of the variables (`Location`) as a location dummy. There are around 3,600 different values and currently the `Location` is a string. I read that it might be faster for Pandas to use categorical variables, so I try to run the following code:

```
df["Location_Cat"] = df.Location.astype("category")
```

However, this makes my computer run like crazy and after 2 minutes, I still don't get a response.

Do you have any idea why this could be the case? Or is it generally not recommended to create category columns with so many categories?

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use `df["Location"] = df.Location.astype("category")` ? Seems like you are adding a new series -> increasing memory requirements otherwise.

Comment: I just did it for test purposes. Since I have 40 variables, I did not expect adding one more would make the difference.